# How to activate Kuler in photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-kuler

I have kuler installed, was using it just fine, then I just change from the move tool to the crop tool and back again. Now kuler window is just blank.

How can I activate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is under one of the top right menu items like "Window->Extensions"

[image: Like So:]

Comment: Hi there - we would rather have a well founded answer. You can use the comment fields for this kind of not-entirely-certain comments.

Comment: Thanks @RandomO'Reilly, I was on my iPad and wasn't near my computer.  I have attached a screenshot of the location as to confirm my original answer.

Comment: Excellent! Much more useful, and uncertainty expelled! :)